# Directory permission setup for drupal 8 in local environment

Tags: php, linux, drupal, permissions, drupal-8

I've read through the official docs of drupal 8 and still don't get the idea of how to setup correct permission of the folders and files.
[image: screenshote]

When we give `777` permission it might work but it's not an elegant way to do so, is there any easy way to setup permission. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

If your system is running with an enforced security policy (SELinux) you may have to set the appropriate rules for httpd/drupal to run properly.

Other than that, following requirements as specified in [INSTALL.TXT](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21INSTALL.txt/8.5.x) should be enough.

**Missing files directory :**

```
mkdir sites/default/files
chmod a+w sites/default/files
```

You can also set permissions on `sites/default/` as well so that your web server is able to create directories under this path :

```
chmod a+w sites/default
```

---

**Missing settings.php :**

```
cp sites/default/default.settings.php sites/default/settings.php
```

Make it writable for the installation :

```
chmod a+w sites/default/settings.php
```

And once the installation is finished, set the permissions back :

```
chmod go-w sites/default/settings.php
```

---

**Multisite :**

For a multisite installation you would replace `default` by the site directory :

```
mkdir sites/example.com/files
chmod a+w sites/example.com/files
cp sites/default/defaults.settings.php sites/example.com/settings.php
```